# Creating alexa skill of web application in hibernate framework hosted on AWS elastics beanstalk

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have created a web application (demo: http://demo.dhruval.tech or http://helloco.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/userRegistration.jsp) of Shopping cart hosted on AWS elastic beanstalk. I want to develop Alexa skill for this web application which takes credentials from a user via Alexa voice and validates them. After this, Alexa will ask which items the user wants to add in cart and checkout.

A web application is running successfully on AWS. I have tried to use AWS Lambda and Alexa skill kit but a bit confused about how to integrate them in Java hibernate. I also have tried to use AWS S3 to generate and store bill of user which user can download manually via clicking on generated URL or via selecting option to send the bill to a mailbox.

There will be two ways to order from the web application.

1. Using web browser 2. Using Alexa skill voice command

When a user opts for the 2nd option, Alexa will ask for credentials and validates them. After validation Alexa will ask which items the user wants to add in cart. Later on, it will check out.

The web application is running smoothly except that bill generation. Need suggestions for how to link Alexa with Java Hibernate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create an Alexa Skill that gets data from an HTTP/HTTPS API (using "Alexa Skills Kit" for Node.js on AWS Lambda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424614/how-do-i-create-an-alexa-skill-that-gets-data-from-an-http-https-api-using-ale)

Comment: @Shashwat I am not knowing node.js otherwise I was recommended this question previously.